# JavaScript variable poofs out of existence in findById callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, closures

Inside this bit of code, the `req` parameter is defined, but when I get inside the callback, it isn't anymore. I can still get to it via `res.req` (weird), though. What happened? I thought that the function would close over its environment.

```
function addDocument(req, res) {
    // in scope
    Request.findById(req.body._id, function(error, request){
        if (request) {
            // disappeared
        } else {
            res.send404('Couldn\'t find a request with that ID.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you don't use the `req` variable inside the function, it was not captured.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't [defined] anymore"? As in it returns the value `undefined`, or you get a reference error when trying to use it, or...? **Please show the code where you tried to use it.**

Comment: @nnnnnn I have no idea what happened. I was trying to access it in a repl, but it seems like things are working fine now. So strange.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you d do that, all simply

```
function addDocument(req, res) {
    // in scope
    Request.findById(req.body._id, function(error, request){
        if (request) {
            req.whatever; // What is Request.findById for ?
        } else {
            res.send404('Couldn\'t find a request with that ID.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's what he's doing. But he's saying `req.whatever` doesn't work. Indeed `req` doesn't exist when he tried. I know, what he says shouldn't be possible but that's what he claims happens. We need more clarification.

Comment: agreed, maybe there is variable conflicts... somewhere in the code we can t read.

Comment: @slebetman I have no idea what happened. I was trying to access it in a repl, but it seems like things are working fine now. So strange.